# Issue trying to convert HTML to Ajax

Tags: html, ajax, smarty

I got this in the video script that I use for my website (Videos Page Layout):

```
<div class="video-views pull-left">
    {$videos[i].viewnumber|kilo} {if $videos[i].viewnumber == '1'}{t c='global.view'}{else}{t c='global.views'}{/if}
</div>
```

Related videos section uses Ajax for videos page layout generated with the "show more" button.

My problem is: I don't know how to convert the "kilo" function in Ajax {$videos[i].viewnumber|kilo}. I attempted a few things but with no result.

```
$code[]     = '<div class="video-views pull-left">';
$views      = ($video['viewnumber'] == '1') ? $lang['global.view'] : $lang['global.views'];
$code[]     = $video['viewnumber']. ' '.$views;
$code[]     = '</div>';
```

Comment: The script is written in Smarty.

Answer (score 0):

Kilo is not a modifier that is included in the Smarty distribution, but if you have access to the code on your site, you can extract the code from the plugin file, it is most likely in `smarty/libs/plugins/modifier.kilo.php`.

It looks like you're working in PHP to construct a response to an AJAX request, so you can just pull that code out and re-use it.

If you do not have access to the modifier file, you can just recreate the formatting on your own. Judging by the context, it's something simple like:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Format integers into human readable strings indicating number of thousands
 * Example: 1200 -> 1.2K
 * @param int $value
 * @return string
 */
function kilo(int $value): string
{
    // If the value is less than 1000, just return it
    if($value < 1000)
    {
        return $value;
    }

    /*
     * If the value is evenly divisible by 1000, we want to show a whole number,
     * otherwise format it as a single precision float. Add "K" string literal
     * to indicate thousands
     */
    $formatString = ($value % 1000) ? '%.1fK':'%dK';

    // Divide value by 1000
    $value /= 1000;

    // Return the formatted string
    return sprintf($formatString, $value);
}

// Define some test data and echo the formatted values
$testViewCounts = [1, 123, 1230, 12300, 123000];
foreach($testViewCounts as $views)
{
    // If only one view, do not pluralize
    $label = ($views == 1) ? 'view':'views';
    echo kilo($views).' '.$label.PHP_EOL;
}
```